# Finding the first element with a specific distance

Tags: java, recursion, tree, kdtree

I'm trying to write a method, which will return the index of a point which is closest to another point in 3D space. The points are stored in a KD-tree and I'm comparing them with the point p which is a parameter of my method. Here is the method:

```
public int NearestPointWithDistance(KDnnTreeNode node, Point p, Double distance){
  int index = -1;
  if(node == null){
     return -1;
  }else{
      double[] point_coordinates = data[node.eltIndex];
      Point q = new Point(point_coordinates[0],point_coordinates[1], point_coordinates[2]);
      if(KDnnTree.distance(p, q) == distance){
             return index;
      }  

      if(node.left != null){
          final int left_child = NearestPointWithDistance(node.left, p, distance);
      }
      if(node.right != null){
          final int right_child = NearestPointWithDistance(node.right, p, distance);
        }
    }
  return index;
```

}

The problem is, there could be multiple points with the same distance. The result I get is a list of indexes of points(see below), but I want only the first element of the list (in the example below, that would be the number 54510).

```
54510
54511
54512
54514
54518
54526
54543
54577
65355
76175
54482
54416
54278
21929
54001
74323
```

I know this is not the way to search two closes points in a KD tree, but I would like to try this way first.

Comment: You need to compare the result from left and right and take only one.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `java.lang.Double` as argument. Use `double`.

The reason is that if your `KDNTree.distance()` would also return `Double` you will end up in comparing references of objects, not their values.

You have pretty inconvenient API. Anyway, make a helper function:

```
public Point getNodePoint(Node node)
{
    double[] point_coordinates = data[node.eltIndex];
    return new Point(point_coordinates[0],point_coordinates[1], point_coordinates[2]);
}
```

Use the best distance availabale selections:

```
double result = KDnnTree.distance(p, q);
if (result == distance)
{
   return node.eltIndex;
}
index = node.eltIndex; // assume given node is best
if (node.left !=  null)
{
    final int left_child = NearestPointWithDistance(node.left, p, distance);
    double left_distance = KDnnTree.distance(p, getNodePoint(left_child);

    if (Math.abs(distance - result) > Math.abs(distance - left_distance))
    {
        // result given is closer to wanted point
        result = left_distance;
        index = left_child;
    }
}
if (node.right !=  null)
{
    final int right_child = NearestPointWithDistance(node.right, p, distance);
    double right_distance = KDnnTree.distance(p, getNodePoint(right_child);

    if (Math.abs(distance - result) > Math.abs(distance - right_distance))
    {
        // result given is closer to wanted point
        result = right_distance;
        index = right_child;
    }
}
return index;
```